# How to interpret a partial derivative where variable in numerator doesn't denote a function?

Tags: derivatives

I encountered the following passage (Option Trading, Euan Sinclair, 2010, p.45):

```
Calls are increasing functions of the underlying.
```

$$  \frac{∂C}{∂S} > 0 $$

`C` denotes an American option and `S` denotes the stock.

My understanding of partial derivatives is that the variable on top denotes a function and not a variable.

How do you interpret this passage?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sometimes the line between a function and a variable is blurred. Here I imagine $C$ is both a variable and a function. It's a function in the sense that its value depends on other variables like the price of the stock. So you might see somewhere in your text something like $C=C(S,\ldots)$. meaning that $C$ is shorthand for a function.